# Random numbers between -1 and 1 summing to 0

Tags: r, algorithm, random

With R, how to generate `n` random numbers `x_1`, ..., `x_n` that lie between `-1` and `1` and that sum to `0`?

What about the generalization to another sum and another range?

Comment: I'm curious about the soundness of a highly un-mathematical solution for the non-generalized version: Generate `n-1` random numbers in that range and `sum` them.  The `n`th number is `(0 - sum)`.

Comment: @WalterGR The sum is not in the range.

Comment: What distribution do you expect? How random does it need to be?

Comment: Agreed with @Bergi; the problem is **not well specified**. There is a math question that needs to be answered here before a programming question can be answered.

Comment: One way to salvage this question: Specify whether the return value should be i.i.d. uniformly distributed over the set of return values that satisfy the conditions (e.g., the components lie in [-1, 1] and sum to 0).

Comment: @PeterO. They can't be independent since they sum to a constant. Usually when one doesn't specify the distribution, we mean a uniform one. "Random" in the layman language means "uniformly distributed". But other solutions are interesting too. E.g. simple ones or parametric ones.

Comment: I don't mean the components themselves are independent, but rather the _vectors_ of numbers that sum to 0 are independent (of other vectors).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***First of all, I would say that, the approaches below are just possible implementations for the constrained randomness, but not secure for the uniform distribution property or something like that.***

---

- ## Recursion

Following a recursion idea, we can generate `r` first with more boundary constraints, which might speed up a lot and be ***much more efficient***

```
f <- function(s, n, a, b) {
  if (s < n * a || s > n * b) {
    stop("Invalid parameters.")
  }
  if (n == 1) {
    return(s)
  }
  r <- runif(1, max(a, s - (n - 1) * b), min(b, s - (n - 1) * a))
  c(r, Recall(s - r, n - 1, a, b))
}
```

and we can see

```
> (v <- f(s = 60, n = 30, a = 1, b = 3))
 [1] 1.544962 1.229845 2.013064 1.510149 2.933672 1.782947 1.650229 2.700521
 [9] 1.151468 1.758759 2.035019 1.355591 2.731922 2.918394 2.288166 2.198345
[17] 1.313646 2.312720 1.232810 1.591426 1.020105 2.788073 1.208734 2.929171
[25] 1.397976 2.044319 1.593190 2.961647 2.849886 2.953244

> summary(v)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
  1.002   1.387   2.126   2.000   2.585   2.892

> length(v)
[1] 30

> sum(v)
[1] 60
```

---

- ## Rejection Sampling

A brute-force (***inefficient***) but lazy approach is rejection sampling

```
f <- function(s, n, a, b) {
  repeat {
    v <- runif(n, a, b)
    x <- s * v / sum(v)
    if (all(x >= a & x <= b)) break
  }
  x
}
```

such that

```
> (v <- f(s = 60, n = 30, a = 1, b = 3))
 [1] 1.800257 1.706306 2.855300 2.177379 2.844279 2.293842 1.011653 2.820371
 [9] 2.803390 2.427355 1.892209 1.829180 2.240873 1.641185 2.267275 1.899986
[17] 1.042455 1.400519 2.612722 1.018635 2.024762 1.413173 1.376111 2.685723
[25] 1.886224 2.151509 1.598368 1.114850 2.303480 2.860629

> summary(v)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
  1.012   1.609   1.962   2.000   2.396   2.861

> length(v)
[1] 30

> sum(v)
[1] 60
```

Comment: No, the Dirichlet distribution generates vectors which sum to `1`, not to `0`. And the components lie between 0 and 1.

Comment: That sounds good. Are the components exchangeable? (that is to say the distribution does not depend on the order of the components)

Comment: I'm going to check the exchangeability. But anyway, if it is not exchangeable, you can apply a random permutation at the end.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I have no idea if "exchangeability" holds here.

Comment: No it doesn't hold. The first component is uniform, not the subsequent ones. I checked with n=3.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Could you add the details of checking exchangeability in your question? Others with related experience might drop by and help you on it.

Comment: A random permutation is applied at the end of the DRS, so there is obviously exchangeability. You can apply such a random permutation too with your method. I checked the two methods yield different distributions, but yours is simpler.

Comment: Does your method can be generalized to bounds `a_i` and `b_i` for `x_i`, depending on `i`? That would be great;

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I think we should finish your first goal, i.e., implementing the exchangeability, before moving onto your next question (element-wise `a_i` and `b_i` for `x_i`).

Comment: I already told you :-) Apply a random permutation at the end, and that's it. But this will not be possible with the individual constraints `a_i` and `b_i`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, you are right. Element-wise constraints cannot come along with permutation, but I think it can be easily implemented based on my recursion code.

Comment: Why is this better than generating random points in [0,1] or any range, then shifting & stretching to get the desired average & width?

Comment: @Dave This question has both element-wise and sum constraints. Are you sure your "shifting + stretching" strategy won't violate those constraints?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding When I test it, I get numbers in the range (-1, 1) that average to zero within floating tolerance (i.e. about 10^-17). Code is in my answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75833711/2041077

Answer (score 11):

#### Simple solution to the first problem

Here is a simple solution to the first problem.
Simulate `u_1`, ..., `u_n` between `-1` and `1`.
Then set `x_1 = (u_1-u_n)/2`, `x_2 = (u_2-u_1)/2`, `x_3 = (u_3-u_2)/2`, ..., `x_n = (u_n-u_{n-1})/2`.

```r
n <- 10L
u <- runif(n, -1, 1)
x <- c(u[1L]-u[n], diff(u)) / 2
sum(x)
summary(x)
```

#### Generalization to an arbitrary sum

##### Now, how to generate `n` random numbers `x_1`, ..., `x_n` that lie between `-1` and `1` and that sum to a given number `s` (between `-n` and `n`)?

Proceed as before but subtract `s/n` to the `u_i` and add `s/n` to the `x_i`:

```r
s <- 3
n <- 10L
u <- runif(n, -1, 1) - s/n
x <- c(u[1L]-u[n], diff(u))/2 + s/n
sum(x)
summary(x)
```

#### Generalization to an arbitrary range?

##### Now, how to generate `n` random numbers `x_1`, ..., `x_n` that lie between two given numbers `a` and `b` and that sum to a given number `s` (between `n*a` and `n*b`)?

The previous method can be generalized to the case **`a = -b`**:

```r
a <- -4; b <- 4; s <- 10
n <- 10L
u <- runif(n, -(b-a)/2, (b-a)/2) - s/n
x <- c(u[1L]-u[n], diff(u))/2 + s/n
sum(x)
summary(x)
```

### Finally, the DRS algorithm

The [Dirichlet-rescale algorithm](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Erd17/papers/DRSPresentation.pdf) solves the last question for any pair of numbers `a < b`.

Moreover, the simulated vector `(x_1, ..., x_n)` has the ***uniform distribution*** on the `(n-1)`-dimensional manifold `{sum x_i = s}`, `a <= x_i <= b`.

Here is a R implementation, adapted from the Matlab implementation written by Roger Stafford (reference given in the code).

```r
# adapted from Roger Stafford's Matlab implementation
# Roger Stafford (2023). Random Vectors with Fixed Sum (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum), MATLAB Central File Exchange. Retrieved March 23, 2023.
DRS <- function(n, s, a, b) {
  n <- as.integer(n)
  if(s < n*a || s > n*b || a >= b) {
    stop("Invalid parameters.")
  }
  # Rescale to a unit cube: 0 <= x(i) <= 1
  s <- (s - n*a) / (b - a)
  # Construct the transition probability table, t.
  #   t(i,j) will be used only in the region where j <= i + 1.
  k <- max(min(as.integer(floor(s)), n-1L), 0L) # Must have 0 <= k <= n-1
  s <- max(min(s, k+1L), k)                     # Must have k <= s <= k+1
  s1 <- s - (k:(k-n+1L))   # s1 will never be negative
  s2 <- ((k+n):(k+1L)) - s # s2 will never be negative
  w <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n+1L)
  w[1L, 2L] <- .Machine$double.xmax # Scale for full 'double' range
  t <- matrix(0, nrow = n-1L, ncol = n)
  tiny <- .Machine$double.eps # The smallest positive 'double' 
  for(i in 2L:n) {
    tmp1 <- w[i-1L, 2L:(i+1L)] * s1[1L:i] / i
    tmp2 <- w[i-1L, 1L:i] * s2[(n-i+1L):n] / i
    w[i, 2L:(i+1L)] <- tmp1 + tmp2
    tmp3 <- w[i, 2L:(i+1L)] + tiny               # In case tmp1 & tmp2 are both 0,
    tmp4 <- as.double(s2[(n-i+1L):n] > s1[1L:i]) #   then t is 0 on left & 1 on right
    t[i-1L, 1L:i] <- (tmp2 / tmp3) * tmp4 + (1 - tmp1 / tmp3) * (1 - tmp4)
  }
  # Derive the polytope volume v from the appropriate element in the bottom row of w.
  v <- n^(3/2) * (w[n, k+2L] / .Machine$double.xmax) * (b - a)^(n - 1L)
  # Now construct the vector x.
  x <- numeric(n)
  rt <- runif(n - 1L) # For random selection of simplex type
  rs <- runif(n - 1L) # For random location within a simplex
  j <- k + 1L # For indexing in the t table
  sm <- 0 # Start with sum zero
  pr <- 1 # Start with product 1
  for(i in (n-1L):1L) { # Work backwards in the t table
    e <- as.double(rt[n-i] <= t[i, j]) # Use rt to choose a transition
    sx <- rs[n-i] ^ (1L/i)             # Use rs to compute next simplex coordinate
    sm <- sm + (1 - sx) * pr * s / (i + 1L) # Update sum
    pr <- sx * pr                           # Update product
    x[n-i] <- sm + pr * e # Calculate x using simplex coordinates
    s <- s - e
    j <- j - e # Transition adjustment
  }
  x[n] <- sm + pr * s # Compute the last x
  # Randomly permute the order in x and rescale
  p <- order(runif(n)) # it is a random permutation
  a + (b - a) * x[p]
}
```

Example:

```r
x <- DRS(n = 10L, s = 14, a = 1, b = 2)
sum(x)
summary(x)
```

---

## EDIT

Something wrong: this is *not* the DRS - see the slides in the given link. The DRS more generally allows different bounds for the `x_i`.

---

## EDIT

I've just found that this method is implemented in the R package [Surrogate](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/Surrogate/html/RandVec.html).

Comment: I think your solution looks too complicated -- a version of @Thomasiscoding's deleted solution would be simpler.  But your statement of the distribution is wrong.  E.g. `x <- DRS(n = 10, s = 10.1, a = 1, b = 2)` is not uniform on `{sum x_i = s}`, there's some upper and lower limits (which are a subset of the range `[a,b]`, not equal to it).

Comment: Ah yes I forgot a and b in the statement. Will edit.

Comment: @user2554330 I believe the constraints are `a` and `b`, why do you say they would be a subset of this range?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, see my latest edit, this is not the DRS in my answer. See [this paper](https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/167646/1/DRSRTSS2020.pdf).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent:  A simpler example would be n = 10, s = 0.01, a = 0, b = 1.  Then the support is claimed to be the simplex of 10 numbers between 0 and 1 that sums to 0.01.  Clearly no number in that sum can be bigger than s, so the range must be [0, 0.01].

Comment: @user2554330 Indeed, you are right. I'm surprised this is not mentioned in the paper.

Comment: Maybe it's uniform on the support of the distribution.

Comment: One thing I had wrong:  I thought all solutions would be simplex shaped, but that's not so.  The support for n=3, a=0.25, b=0.4, s=1 is a hexagon.

Comment: Just a note: The DRS algorithm for the question's first problem (generate numbers in [-1,1] that sum to 0) appears to generate numbers in [0,2] that sum to n, then subtract 1 from each coordinate.  This suggests that, in many cases, generating positive and/or negative numbers with a given sum can be reduced to generating only positive numbers with a given upper bound and the appropriate positive sum.

Answer (score 6):

Roger Stafford’s algorithm does not handle non-identical bounds, since
it cleverly exploits the symmetry of the identical bounds case to sample
efficiently in the worst case.

The Dirichlet-Rescale (DRS) algorithm handles non-identical bounds but
is essentially generate-and-test (which is not efficient in the worst
case) with one trick. The trick is that, when we’re sampling
x<sub>i</sub> ∈ [a<sub>i</sub>, b<sub>i</sub>] subject to
∑x<sub>i</sub> = s, we can either

- Generate x<sub>i</sub> − a<sub>i</sub> ≥ 0 with ∑x<sub>i</sub> = s
  and test x<sub>i</sub> ≤ b<sub>i</sub>;
- Generate b<sub>i</sub> − x<sub>i</sub> ≥ 0 with ∑x<sub>i</sub> = s
  and test a<sub>i</sub> ≤ x<sub>i</sub>.

The first option is better if ∑(a<sub>i</sub> + b<sub>i</sub>)/2 < s,
and the second option is better if ∑(a<sub>i</sub> + b<sub>i</sub>)/2 >
s. (The original DRS presentation is much more complicated.)

The other feature of DRS is that it works hard not to consume more
randomness than it needs, but this is a blunder in my opinion because
there may be weird floating-point effects for multi-iteration samples,
and random numbers just aren’t that expensive.

In (poorly tested) R:

```
DRS_upper <- function(s, u) {
    if (length(u) == 0 || any(u <= 0)) {
        stop("Invalid parameters.")
    }
    repeat {
        x <- diff(c(0, sort(runif(length(u) - 1, 0, s)), s))
        if (all(x <= u)) {
            return(x)
        }
    }
}

DRS <- function(s, a, b) {
    if (length(a) == 0 || length(b) == 0 || length(a) != length(b) || any(a >= b) ||
        s <= sum(a) || sum(b) <= s) {
        stop("Invalid parameters.")
    }
    if (s - sum(a) < sum(b) - s) {
        return(DRS_upper(s - sum(a), b - a) + a)
    }
    return(b - DRS_upper(sum(b) - s, b - a))
}

# Example
DRS(10, c(1, 2, 3), c(3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: It looks simple. This is really the DRS ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the complexity of DRS has two sources. 1. They go to a lot of trouble to compute the probability of accepting a sample, but they actually only care which of two is larger. This is equivalent to the test `s - sum(a) < sum(b) - s`. 2. They go to a lot of trouble to remap rejected samples back to the Dirichlet simplex, which is where I diverge slightly because why? The remapped sample isn't more likely to be accepted than a fresh random sample, but it is definitely lower precision. Computational cost should be about the same.

Comment: (Also I use a different Dirichlet sampling method that avoids log.) IMO the conference reviewers should have noticed this, but given the conference, it's not surprising that they didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on sampling from the Dirichlet.

```r
# Sample points uniformly on the simplex sum x_i = s, subject to
# constraints a < x_i < b, i = 1, ... m.

# First, transform to the [0, 1]^m cube by working with 
# y_i = (x_i - a)/(b - a)
# The sum becomes s' = (s - ma)/(b - a).

# If s' < 0 or s' > m there are no solutions, so quit.

# If s' < 1, the constraints don't matter, so rescale a Dirichlet:
#  z ~ Dirichlet(1, ..., 1), set y = z * s'

# If s' < m/2, use rejection sampling on a rescaled Dirichlet:
#  z ~ Dirichlet(1, ..., 1), Keep trying until y = z * s' is all
# within [0, 1].  All y values are automatically positive


# If s' > m/2 we'd reject too much, so work with 1 - y_i instead.

# At the end transform back to the original scale, 
# x = (b - a) y + a

# Uses brms and rgl packages

rRescaleDirichlet <- function(n, m, a, b, s) {
  s1 <- (s - m*a)/(b - a)
  if (s1 < 0 || s1 > m)
    stop("Parameters are out of range.")
  
  if (s1 > m/2) {
    flip <- TRUE
    s1 <- m - s1
  } else
    flip <- FALSE
  
  result <- matrix(NA, 0, m)
  oversample <- if (s1 < 1) 1 else 2
  n0 <- n
  while (n > 0) {
    z <- brms::rdirichlet(oversample*n, rep(1, m)) 
    y <- z * s1
    y <- y[apply(y, 1, function(x) all(x < 1)), ]
    keep <- min(n0 - nrow(result), nrow(y))
    result <- rbind(result, y[seq_len(keep),])
    n <- n0 - nrow(result)
  }
  if (flip)
    result <- 1 - result
  
  (b-a)*result + a
}

x <- rRescaleDirichlet(10000, 3, -1, 1, 0)
summary(x)
#>        V1                  V2                  V3           
#>  Min.   :-0.999990   Min.   :-0.999491   Min.   :-0.999842  
#>  1st Qu.:-0.426692   1st Qu.:-0.431709   1st Qu.:-0.423248  
#>  Median :-0.006093   Median : 0.001340   Median : 0.021912  
#>  Mean   :-0.005533   Mean   :-0.001905   Mean   : 0.007438  
#>  3rd Qu.: 0.405129   3rd Qu.: 0.420720   3rd Qu.: 0.425665  
#>  Max.   : 0.999463   Max.   : 0.999554   Max.   : 0.999787
rgl::plot3d(x)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach.

- Generate n floats between 0 and 1
- Shift by left by the average of these points
- Stretch all points away from 0 to fill the space desired.

Here's Ruby code to accomplish this. The mult in the code below handles the stretching. The stretching factor I use is designed to preserve the more conservative of the two distances between the extreme points and the range, after a doubling factor (to account for doubling the range)

```
def f(n)
  arr = []
  n.times do
    arr.append(rand)
  end
  
  avg = arr.sum / n
  leftmost_pt = -1 + 2 * arr.min
  rightmost_pt = 2 * arr.max - 1
  mult = [leftmost_pt / (arr.min - avg), rightmost_pt / (arr.max - avg)].min

  0.upto(n-1) do |i|
    arr[i] -= avg
    arr[i] *= mult
  end
  
  puts arr.sort.to_s
end
```

Sample Results:

```
> f(100)
[-0.9891868749476447, -0.9841797959702733, -0.848670830904512, -0.8483229277098323, -0.8411655155224181, -0.8324813381638559, -0.8181055804749083, -0.8079457473507614, -0.800987369937368, -0.7577576633783468, -0.7524936016842146, -0.7115445481559692, -0.6991425474171663, -0.6795757863364923, -0.6701781937582226, -0.6384927466389793, -0.6294964939183588, -0.6155664737630111, -0.5878014621149229, -0.5764696924978272, -0.5668841490309326, -0.5626603830488923, -0.5615953223333867, -0.5570822656913642, -0.5266628529945551, -0.48092505889101683, -0.46956100587764715, -0.4523341826710813, -0.4401174739476492, -0.43464401255527946, -0.42689187575599197, -0.4213913910405733, -0.38299537530720656, -0.3694495642896308, -0.2961361727287325, -0.28288156441036016, -0.23051721058762914, -0.22371836542884754, -0.20203604935005437, -0.16509606938681623, -0.15707841345756854, -0.14868405790953576, -0.11640501178558098, -0.09294898114518457, -0.09294832773848151, -0.02677332280186984, -0.010445732538003323, -0.007105127384422116, -0.004688040162969207, -0.0016748675082990008, 0.0070890488405637615, 0.015588732468742478, 0.06367463840208484, 0.06953757311859611, 0.08421785548733109, 0.0959447831422179, 0.11215579415565466, 0.16096550839479273, 0.16920990193823807, 0.1811855346946572, 0.18408755203001037, 0.18746303880386458, 0.23421156348587155, 0.24323063939140882, 0.24843662466506716, 0.26230264559033567, 0.2624774985463022, 0.263258301559409, 0.28314031656832084, 0.32070923475089447, 0.35435257074172066, 0.3748873647098375, 0.37923050659537216, 0.3852748462223294, 0.3923950709817138, 0.40799869447822296, 0.4844140183938689, 0.49290817630507755, 0.5020129260996314, 0.5152049976626806, 0.5338640544525307, 0.562752760795784, 0.6377096362138428, 0.6611913612619461, 0.6942175882927449, 0.7197736567323416, 0.7428400038132111, 0.7993062785764886, 0.8325002381387803, 0.8337771194652699, 0.8376220163644345, 0.8609672399947833, 0.8666284648034757, 0.8684073542091211, 0.8692456799466243, 0.926340770835069, 0.9455048113008502, 0.9486137984715667, 0.9500553302312981, 0.9730132962796711]
avg: 4.690909119475784e-17
```

Comment: If the average of the original set of points (before you shift & stretch) is significantly off from 0.1, then, while all the points will be in [-1, 1] in the adjusted version, either the leftmost endpoint will be significantly > -1, or the rightmost will be significantly < 1. The more points you have, the less likely this is.

Answer (score 1):

Take the sum of all your numbers. Calculate the mean. Subtract the mean from each number. Divide by the new maximum absolute value. You now have a new random distribution whose mean is 0.0 and whose values are in [-1.0,1.0].